# input and dynamic textfield cant get new value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flash

Basicly the problem. very strange problem.

- i cant assign a new value to a dynamic field by code.
- i cant write into a input field on flash player.

you're ganna need the fla file. i made it simplify. not complicated.
http://www.sundanceresidences.com/formTest.zip

i be appreciated if you dont ask code. it is not the case here. if you really want to help just test the file.

Thanks.

Comment: I think there is problem with your flash exporting, because I have exported from my flash and its working fine.

Comment: Do not link your file but show your code here!

Comment: code is not the problem.

Comment: @Senad, i don't know what option could cause this.

Comment: viaria, code is (almost) always the problem.

Comment: @sam, well, this is not one of them. if you just test the file you can see.

Comment: I have tested the file. Without being able to inspect the code, I have no idea what is causing your problems. We can't *fix* things we can't *see*.

Comment: you dont have to inspect anything, you have no idea what cause this just like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using flash ide to create textfields, i always work this way until i see this unknown error. This is happening sometimes. 
The solution is creation textfields by code. With this way i had to format and style fields. i made an example if people come here from google.

```
    var name_txt:TextField;
    name_txt = new TextField();
    name_txt.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    name_txt.x = 10;
    name_txt.y = 10;
    name_txt.width = 338;
    name_txt.height = 20;
    name_txt.multiline = false;
    name_txt.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.NORMAL;
    addChild(name_txt);     

    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();  
    myFormat.color = 0x093F51;
    myFormat.size = 12;
    myFormat.bold = true;
    myFormat.letterSpacing = "1";
    myFormat.font = "PT Sans Bold";

    name_txt.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
```